# Does google play store and apple app store still support ionic v1 apps?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I have an app built using `ionic` version 1, I have to push it live now. Does apple and google still support `ionic v1` or I have to shift it to latest version ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that there is no problem in publishing that type of apps. It does not matter with what version they were made, but that they meet the requirements for the store.

In `Android` openly accept any type of app, the process is not as rigorous and the restrictions are minimal. Then there is more possibility.

As for `iOS-Apple`, they have to go through a process of quality. They are much more rigorous and it is more frequent that they can reject it.

You must publish it and then it will enter a revision period, when it is ready you will be informed if there was a problem.